# error renaming columns in single cell object?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioconductor

I'm getting an error message I can't explain in R.

In my singlecellexperiment object sce_ch_dv I want to name all cells who are cluster 4 (clusterName is 4) with "Macrophage" in a sepearte column. However I am getting this error:

```
Error in .normarg_Rvalue(Rvalue, selection_dim) :    length of replacement value must equal the number of array elements to replace
```

The following is the code that produces the error:

```
macrophage <- grep("4", sce_ch_dv$clusterName)
sce_ch_dv$mac <- NA
sce_ch_dv[,macrophage]$mac<- "Macrophage"
```

macrophage is of class integer, length 18. The single cell object has 182 cells, 18 of which would therefore need to have the word "macrophage" in an additional column.

I'm at a loss, since this code has previously worked when I did it. What might have changed?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think the error comes from `sce_ch_dv[,macrophage]$mac<- "Macrophage"` which should be `sce_ch_dv[macrophage,]$mac<- "Macrophage"` because you intend to replace by rows and not columns

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).